# How can I show bathymetry data on all zoom levels in my custom style?

Tags: mapbox

I have no idea how to make the bathymetry layer show on the most zoomed out zoom layer. It only seems to activate when I go above level 3 zoom.

I don't have any opacity changes based on zoom, it's just set to 1, so I don't know why it's not showing. Is it because we can't view complex data when fully zoomed out or zomething?

### zoom at 2.9

[image: not showing bathymetry]

### zoom at 3.1

[image: showing bathymetry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, your bathyrmetry tileset only exists at zoom levels 3 and above. There's nothing you can do to make it appear at levels below its minimum.